# Where To Find Host Class For Using Statements in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot/)

and like many other tutorials, it is very vague as to where to insert code.  Which vb.net file would I insert the host class to begin adding the *using statement*?

I have a file called crawler.aspx...this accepts html and the like.  I also have crawler.aspx.vb...tried adding the code there and received an error saying that the statement could not be used outside of the method/body lambda.

Comment: Do you mean the `using statement` or the `using directive`?  The equivalent in VB.NET for the latter is `Imports`.   But it's not clear from your question or the link what exactly you mean....

Comment: 1: Add the following using statements to the host class...

using Abot.Crawler;
using Abot.Poco;     This is all it says...hence...my confusion.  Not sure what I should be asking.  I have seen the "using statements before, usually under the module name.  Other than that...I don't know what I should be asking.  Any direction you could point me in would be helpful.

Comment: After re-reading your comment, it struck me that I am trying to write in vb.  Most tutorials are in C#.  Maybe the question I should be asking is how to convert the tutorial into VB???

Comment: You can use online converters such as [this](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/) or [this](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx) to convert C# to VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example is in C#.   The equivalent VB.NET directive is `Imports`.  It tells the compiler that you will be using classes and methods and such from the specified assembly.

As long as you have a reference to the assemblies in your project (which if you installed this via NuGet you should), you can simply add the following lines to the top of your file containing the code of the host class, like this:

```
Imports Abot.Crawler
Imports Abot.Poco
```

This should not be confused with the [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement, which is something different entirely.

Comment: YES! I added the comment above as you were answering this.  I rewrote to "Imports" within the crawler.aspx.vb file at the very top and did not get an error.  Stay tuned...may have a lot more questions that need to be answered as I try to convert the language.

Comment: @Danimal - That's fine. I recommend if you run into problems converting the language, you should ask a new question and post what you've tried and where you're stuck.  You're more likely to get help that way.  The various online converters should be able to give you most of what you need.